# Why the program is stuck when while loop is used in a recursive call

Tags: c, linked-list

I've written a program to convert a given decimal number to a linked list of its digit. When I execute the below program it hangs but I'm not sure why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *convert_num(int num)
{
  struct node *list = NULL;
  while(num != 0)
  {
    list = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    list->data = num % 10;
    list->next = convert_num(num/10);
  }
  return list;
}

int main()
{
  struct node *n1;
  n1 = convert_num(354);

  return 0;

}
```

This program hangs in `convert_num()` function.

Comment: `while(num != 0)` - why would it be `0` ever?

Comment: Should be `if` instead of `while` (or you should inline the recursion).

Comment: You don't change num inside the loop

Comment: num will be 0 when we insert the last digit 3 into the linked list, 3/10 = 0

Comment: Yes, I guess, I am doing a mistake by while, it should be an if

Comment: @HimanshuDutta Yes, but the recursive call just before that will keep making a call to convert_num forever because of the loop

Comment: And what will happen to the less lucky recursive calls who don't get `num==0`?

Comment: You are combining a recursive LL building function with a iterative LL building function. Neither of them will terminate as neither of them have a base case!

Comment: pass num as a pointer to int and update it in every function call.i.e   int * num , *num/=10 this way by the time recursion completes num would have been updated to 0

Answer (score 5):

Your function has an infinite loop (`num` never changes in `while (num != 0) { }`). Fix:

```
struct node *convert_num(unsigned num)
{
  if (num == 0)
    return NULL;

  struct node *list = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  list->data = num % 10;
  list->next = convert_num(num/10);
  return list;
}
```

or

```
struct node *convert_num(unsigned num)
{
  struct node *head;
  struct node **next_ptr = &head;
  while (num != 0) {
    *next_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    (*next_ptr)->data = num % 10;
    next_ptr = &((*next_ptr)->next);
    num /= 10;
  }

  *next_ptr = NULL;
  return head;
}
```